# Clone of list still correct the original list

Tags: groovy

In groovy the original value get overwritten when I change values in a clone list. Does anyone know if I am doing it wrong or it is a bug older groovy?

I am doing something like this:

```
List<Foo> myFooList = fooList.newFoos.findAll { it.type == "Types}
List<Foo> newFoo = fooList.oldFoos.findAll { it.type == "Types}.clone()

newFoo.each {
   it.value = "neeeew value"
}

Foo fooOne = newFoo.each { foooo ->
   fooTwo = fooList.oldFoos.find { it.id == foooo.id}
   if(fooTwo.value != foooo.value) {
       //Here it should go... but it turns out that fooTwo.value == foooo.value
   }
}
```

Comment: This clones the list, but not the `Foo`.  You would have to do an `...collect{ new Foo(it.properties) }` (or something similar) instead of the `clone`

Comment: You will need to iterate on the items and clone them one by one. For that to work, you will have to get your Foo class to implement the Cloneable interface, and the clone() method.

Comment: @cfrick he is comparing primitive properties of the foo object though; although the object references are not equal they primitive properties are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding clone of the element as well, any way it became to much of cowboy fix:

```
List<Foo> myFooList = fooList.newFoos.findAll { it.type == "Types}
List<Foo> newFoo = fooList.oldFoos.findAll { it.type == "Types}.collect {it.clone()}

newFoo.each {
   it.value = "neeeew value"
}

Foo fooOne = newFoo.each { foooo ->
   fooTwo = fooList.oldFoos.find { it.id == foooo.id}
   if(fooTwo.value != foooo.value) {
       //Here it should go... but it turns out that fooTwo.value == foooo.value
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `clone` method called on list produces a new list but with the same objects in it.

you want to build new list with new objects. here is an example:

```
@groovy.transform.ToString
class Foo{
    String type
    String value
}

def fooList = [
    new Foo(type:"Types", value:'old value1'),
    new Foo(type:"Not",   value:'old value2'),
    new Foo(type:"Types", value:'old value3'),
    new Foo(type:"Not",   value:'old value4'),
]

def newFooList = fooList.
    findAll{it.type=='Types'}.
    collect{ new Foo(type:it.type, value:"new value") } //build new array with transformed elements

//check the original list
fooList.each{assert it.value!='new value'}
//check new list
newFooList.each{assert it.value=='new value'}
assert newFooList.size()==2

println fooList
println newFooList
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking af the clone method. Any way you gave me a idea to solve it by .collect { it.clone }